# JSON format in PHP

Tags: php, json

```
{
  "required_items": [{
      "filename": "abcd",
      "no": "3"
    },
    {
      "filename": "abc",
      "no": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not getting the code of the JSON format in PHP - I want to insert the filename and no through a loop.

Comment: After your edit, your JSON string was still not valid. Also, please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: *(tipp)* [jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Yes, after I edited your source code. [Before that](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/959bfd1c-2f29-48aa-9861-1f403ef862bc/view-source), it wasn't. @Gordon: Nice tip, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to generate the above JSON code in PHP, do something like this:

```
$object->required_items = array();

for( ... your loop here ... )
{
    $item->filename = 'filename';
    $item->no = 1;
    $object->required_items[] = $item;
}

$json = json_encode( $object );
```

Comment: Good day, sir. I tried to use your code. But my output displays only one row from my database (that contains 3 rows). Can you please help me? Thanks. Here's my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806959/php-json-array-not-returning-all-rows-from-my-database

Answer (score 2):

Pass the JSON to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and you'll end up with an regular PHP data structure you can operate on. Use var_dump to take a look at it. When you're done manipulating it, turn it back into JSON with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

I don't know if it's typos on your part, but the format you pasted isn't valid JSON.