# PHP JSON Array not returning all rows from my database

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$retrieve = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`") or die(mysql_error());

$object -> userDetails = array();

while($retrieveArray = mysql_fetch_array($retrieve))
{
    $item -> userId =  $retrieveArray['id'];
    $item -> userEmail = $retrieveArray['email'];
    $item -> userLocation = $retrieveArray['location'];
    $item -> userFirstName = $retrieveArray['firstname'];
    $item -> userLastName = $retrieveArray['lastname'];
    $object ->userDetails[] = $item;
}   
$json = json_encode($object);
echo $json;
```

Is there something wrong with this code? My output only displays the first row of my database.

```
{"userDetails":[{"userId":"1","userEmail":"EmailAddress@gmail.com","userLocation":"HomeAddress","userFirstName":"Allan","userLastName":"Knocks"}]}
```

Comment: @JugalThakkar - They aren't. My problem is that my database contains three rows but my output returns only one. The output is at the lower part of my question.

Comment: Stop using the old `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead. If you `var_dump($item)` inside the while loop, how many times does it print? Since you are not creating a new `$item` object in the loop, the later iterations just rewrite the fields of the existing object - you should do `$item = new stdClass()` or similar inside the loop to avoid this.

Comment: try `array_push($object ->userDetails, $item);` instead of the last line inside your for loop

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() did a different thing. It displayed 3 rows but with the same values.

Comment: array_push($object ->userDetails, $item); did the exact thing with what mysql_fetch_assoc() did. Displayed 3 rows with the same values from the first row.

Comment: Where did you create the object $item? You are assigning to the same instance .. even if you had 5 items in your json they would have the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$retrieve = mysql_query("SELECT id, email, location, firstname, lastname FROM `users`") or die(mysql_error());
$userDetails= array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retrieve)) {
  $userDetails[] = $row;
}   
$json = json_encode(array('userDetails' => $userDetails));
echo $json;
```

Comment: This is great. Short but perfect. Thanks!

Comment: still curious, @xdazz, could you throw some light on the major downside of the previous approach? Why it failed?

Answer (score 1):

Beware! Doing this in a loop will modify the same instance many times and you will end up with the same object added many times to your array:

```
while($retrieveArray = mysql_fetch_array($retrieve))
{
    $item -> userId =  $retrieveArray['id'];
    $item -> userEmail = $retrieveArray['email'];
    $item -> userLocation = $retrieveArray['location'];
    $item -> userFirstName = $retrieveArray['firstname'];
    $item -> userLastName = $retrieveArray['lastname'];
    //you are adding here the same object with changed properties.
    $object ->userDetails[] = $item;
}
```

In the end $object->userDetails will contain n references to the same object with the last set properties.

Instead you should create a new instance inside the loop :

```
while($retrieveArray = mysql_fetch_array($retrieve))
{
    //new item (if there is a class Item)
    $item = new Item();
    // if $item is just a stdObject created on the fly then use 
    $item = new stdClass();
    $item -> userId =  $retrieveArray['id'];
    $item -> userEmail = $retrieveArray['email'];
    $item -> userLocation = $retrieveArray['location'];
    $item -> userFirstName = $retrieveArray['firstname'];
    $item -> userLastName = $retrieveArray['lastname'];
    //you are adding here another object
    $object ->userDetails[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: Lol..that was an example... You didn't post the entire code so I guessed your class name. What's it called?

Comment: No.. I'm sorry if you misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
 $result = $con->query($sql);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {   

  $userDetails = array();
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {     
       $userData[] = array(
        "id" => $row["id"],
        "name" => $row["name"],
        "email" => $row["email"],
     );
   }
} else {
   echo "0 results";
}

 $result1['regular'] = $userData;
 $json = json_encode($result1);
  echo $json;
```

Your json will look like bellow

```
{"regular":[{"id":"2","name":"enamul Haque","email":"ehaque95@gmail.com"},{"id":"55","name":"Rafiq","email":"era@gmail.com"}]}
```